# How to download file With Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift

I want continue download After I press 'startDownload' button, (Use resumeData)
when I second time enter app after app terminated.

Here is my Example code:
https://github.com/wgywgy/AlamofireDownloadDemo/tree/master

where to find resumeData?

Comment: Please add _relevant_ code to your question. DO NOT post links to your repo.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the "cancelledData" in a file and in second time enter app after app terminated you can read the data from that file as NSData.

Comment: where to get cancelledData? which delegate method to find it? thank you.

Comment: In the sample code you linked above, in downloadobject.swift and "downloadResponse" action, you can access to cancelledData.